# Italy student visa question

Tags: visa, student-visa, study, italy, students

I'm going to apply soon for my student visa for Italy as I'm going to study for a Master's degree for 2 years

I have a question about 2 documents.

Proof of accomodation. My university won't publish the names of the people who can stay in the accomodation until late August, so what should I do? Book a hotel? And for how long?

Flight tickets. I've read on many sites that I also need to book a return ticket. When should the return ticket be, at the end of my studying period?

Comment: You should probably get your Italian school's advice first. Did they say anything about it?